# How to find all available links for a particular file in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a file named `testfile.txt` in  `/home/rajeesh/Desktop/My/Assignments/`. I need to search for all the available links to the above-mentioned file using some CLI command.

I tried:

```sh
find -L /home -inum $(ls -di testfile.txt | cut -d" " -f1)
```

I am running this command in directory `/home/rajeesh/Desktop/My/Assignments/` but the result contains only link available in the current directory (I have links for the file on `Desktop` and in `My folders`).

Could anybody help me with this, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the `ls -Ldi` output for `testfile.txt` and those links.

Comment: Tried that as well. Not working.

Comment: What do you mean not working? Do you get an error? Do you get different numbers? Incorporate your answer into your question.

Comment: The *L* in the `ls` is not needed, actually, `ls -i` would be sufficient, since the command is only used to get the inode number of the file in question and to pass it to `find`.

Comment: Yeah nothing happens if I use `-Ldi` or `-di`. What I need is to display all the links to a particular file. So I created 3 links to the file `testfile.txt` and put that in separate folders. But only one in the `pwd` is displayed

Comment: @phunsoft I meant use `ls -L` with the links to show the inode they point to and compare with the inode of `testfile.txt`.

Comment: @RajeeshKV It's not nothing. It outputs the inode number. What is it? Here is my test: `$ touch a; ln -s a b; ln -s a c; ls -Ldi a b c`, which gives `32388550 a  32388550 b  32388550 c`. Do you see the same numbers with your file and links?

Comment: @mkayaalp The `ls` is executed only once for the file in question as part of command substituion. It is not executed for each file found by the `find` command. It is the `-L` in the `find` command which is important.

Comment: @phunsoft I know, I am trying to get @RajeeshKV to identify the problem by making sure the links indeed point to the `testfile.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

If using GNU find:

```sh
find -L /home -samefile /home/rajeesh/Desktop/My/Assignments/testfile.txt
```

will display all files existing in the `/home` directory tree that have the same inode as the given file (Meaning they're hard links to the same underlying file) or are symbolic links pointing to the given file.

Comment: I tried this as well. It gives me the same result as I mentioned in the above. It displays the link in that `pwd` which is `/home/rajeesh/Desktop/My/Assignment/` and not the one in `Desktop` and `My` folders. What I need is to display all links present under `/home`. And yes all links are for the mentioned file only.

Comment: @RajeeshKV How are you creating these links?

Comment: I user `ln` command to create links to different directories. Like `ln -s testfile.txt /home/rajeesh/Desktop/My/LinkFile`

Comment: @RajeeshKV I start to see the problem. Sure those links work? Can you cat them and get the contents of the linked-to file?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326835/367593